# Where to put a binary when root/sudo is not an option?

Tags: linux, installation, permissions

I am currently working on an installer, written in Go. The main part is to automatically put the binary in the right place. This is not a problem with root/sudo permissions, but users don't want to use sudo, because a part of the script is web-loaded, and I totally understand that.

My issue is, that many systems don't have a single path in `$PATH` where non-admin users can write to. Here is the output of a fresh Debian installation:

```
# Permissions

[INFO] Has administrative rights: false

Can write to /usr/local/go/bin: false
Can write to /usr/local/sbin: false
Can write to /usr/local/bin: false
Can write to /usr/sbin: false
Can write to /usr/bin: false
Can write to /sbin: false
Can write to /bin: false
Can write to /usr/games: false
Can write to /usr/local/games: false
```

A fresh Debian installation does not have `~/bin` / `~/.local/bin`, etc.

Those are my options, as far as I am aware of:

- Put the binary in a path and tell the user to add it to the env (not possible, the installer has to be fully automatic)
- Require root/sudo (security concerns => not possible)
- Create a new dir like `~/bin`, put the binary there and add the path to the shell profile automatically (is this a good practise? )

  - If this is acceptable, what path would fit most (`~/bin` / `~/.local/bin`, etc.)?

Please let me know if there is a better option! Currently, only the last one seems to work for me, but I really don't like modifying users shell profiles.

Comment: You're missing the option: ask the user where they want it and ask if they want your installer to mess with their PATH

Comment: @Mat the installation should happen automatically. The installer is a multi-purpose installer and should also provide the ability to be used in scripts/pipelines that have no administrative rights. Setting those settings via flags would be possible, but what would be the best default procedure? Also the installer aims at people with no DevOps experience at all, they probably don't know what shell profiles, env paths, etc. are.

Comment: Is it even required to modify `PATH`? How is the user expected to start the application? Wouldn't a `.desktop` launcher be sufficient? (Inexperienced users wouldn't use the shell anyway.)

Comment: There is no "best default". Document how the user (automated or not) can set where to put stuff.